# Como chamar um modal usando javascript ou outra linguagem que funcione dentro do HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, session, dom

Olá, tenho um modal que tem um form de cadastro, quando eu clico pra cadastrar ele chama um código **PHP**, que cadastra as informações e inicia uma `session` 'cadastro_efetuado'. Após abrir a `session`ele chama a página de volta, onde está esse modal. Ao iniciar essa pagina **HTML**, algumas validações são executadas. Uma dessas validações está abaixo.

O que eu quero fazer, é clicar o botão que abre esse modal quando essa `session` 'cadastro_efetuado' for `true`. Pra quando a pessoa cadastrar um item, a pagina ser recarregada e abrir o modal automaticamente.

Tentei vários códigos, de vários fórums e nenhum deu certo. Se eu colocar um alert nesse script funciona normalmente. Mas esse código: `document.getElementById("btnModalCategoria").click();`
e outros que tentei da erro de ponto virgula ou não da nenhum erro, porém não funciona.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['cadastro_efetuado'])):

    echo "<script>
        document.getElementById("btnModalCategoria").click();
    </script">

    endif;
    unset($_SESSION['cadastro_efetuado']);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seu erro não seja o código javascript mas sim onde ele está sendo renderizado em sua página. Você precisa assegurar que a ação de `click` do botão seja executada quando o mesmo for renderizado, pois não tem como clicar em um botão que não exista. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById("btnModalCategoria").click();
</script>

<button id="btnModalCategoria" onclick="alert('Clicked')">Click</button>
```

Então para assegurar que o script funcione após todo conteúdo HTML ser renderizado, você pode adicionar o script no final de todo conteúdo HTML (antes do fechamento da tag `</body>`)

```html
<body>
  <button id="btnModalCategoria" onclick="alert('Clicked')">Click</button>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("btnModalCategoria").click();
  </script>
</body>
```

Ou utilizar a propriedade [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) para ser "disparada" quando determinado recurso estiver carregado, que neste caso é o [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window).

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("btnModalCategoria").click();
  };
</script>

<button id="btnModalCategoria" onclick="alert('Clicked')">Click</button>
```

Comment: Entendi.. Mas no caso do onload, ele executaria toda vez que a pagina fosse carregada novamente. Eu não queri. Quero só quando a SESSION cadastro_efetuado for true.

Comment: Vou te explicar melhor. O evento `onload` será acionado quando toda a página HTML e seus recursos for renderizado. Caso você coloque um script que manipula um botão antes mesmo que o botão seja renderizado, não irá funcionar. Então o evento `onload` espera os recursos serem carregados para então executar os scripts. E como o seu código JS está dentro da condição se o cadastro for igual a `true`, somente neste caso o script será "embutido" no código.

Comment: Ahhhhh entendi, funcionou mano! Valeu mesmo, estava tentando arrumar isso a dias. Obrigado!!

Comment: Dê nada @natanfoleto, fico feliz em ter te ajudado! Caso uma das respostas de algum usuário te ajudou a obter o resultado esperado, marque-a como melhor resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Olhando para o código em si, inicialmente vocês não está escapando código corretamente do PHP.

Veja que:

```
 echo "<script>
    document.getElementById("btnModalCategoria").click();
</script">
```

é diferente de:

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('btnModalCategoria').click();<script>";
```

Veja se você escreveu certo aqui no forum, caso não corrija por favor.
Isso só falando de escrita pois `.click` é do jQuery e você esta misturando javascript puro com o jQuery, para simular um click usando javascript vai ter que dar uma olhada em algo sobre `fireEvent`.
Outras tentativas podem ser realizadas usando o jQuery:

```
echo '<script>$("#btnModalCategoria").trigger("click");</script>'; //caso use jquery
echo '<script>$("#btnModalCategoria").click();</script>'; //caso use jquery
echo "<script>$('#btnModalCategoria').click();</script>"; //caso use jquery
```

Tendo sempre atenção ao uso das aspas. Se precisar dar um `echo ""` usando aspas duplas e precisar escapar `"`:

```
echo "<script>$(\"#btnModalCategoria\").click();</script>";
```

Comment: O método `click()` não pertence somente a biblioteca JQuery, a interface **HTMLElement** fornece o método `click()` como podemos ler na documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click